# problems with loading embedded swf files in air app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a game file which I create using flash cs 5.5. I have another swf file which is hint file which I embedded in that game file. It works fine in pc. I got problems when I tried to load that game file with embedded swf file. I got the following error:
SecurityError: Error #3226: Cannot import a SWF file when LoaderContext.allowCodeImport is false. Can anyone tell me why is this happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're working with adobe air for mobile on your android device. In air for mobile, there is extra restrictions on loading external SWF files - especially when they contain byte codes(ActionScript). Because your secondary SWF file is containing actionscript code for itself, you cannot load into your mobile air application without explicit security allowance.

AS3 uses `Loader` implicitly when you instantiate classes refering your embedded SWF files, and it loads with default option - which is set to different in air for mobile runtime environment.

You can load them with manual loading, by creating `Loader` and `LoaderContext` instance by yourself.

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
lc.allowCodeImport = true;
ldr.load(new URLRequest("YOUR_FILE_PATH"), lc);
```

Also note that in iOS, even if `allowCodeImport` is set to true, you cannot load external SWF with codes, by any means.

For further details : http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/

Comment: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/03/08/external-hosting-of-secondary-swfs-for-air-apps-on-ios/

Answer (score 1):

Try this kind of Context:

```
var loaderContext: LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true; 
swfLoader.loaderContext = loaderContext;
```